# Keynotfoundexception on creating client

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm getting this error in my WP project:

```
An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

at this:

```
   AzureService.AzureServiceClient client = new AzureService.AzureServiceClient();
```

client = a client from a WCF web service.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

A KeyNotFoundException is thrown when an operation attempts to retrieve an element from a collection using a key that does not exist in that collection.

So i think that when you register your service you have problem when calling, you set mismatch between registered and called service